# "Precise Rules that Govern the Behavior of Floats"

Tags: css, css-float

"A floating box's outer top may not be higher than the top of its containing block. When the float occurs between two collapsing margins, the float is positioned as if it had an otherwise empty anonymous block parent taking part in the flow. The position of such a parent is defined by the rules in the section on margin collapsing."

Can someone explain this rule? It had me confused. How does a float happen between two collapsed margins and how is the float positioned as if it had an otherwise empty anonymous block parent taking part in the flow. ?

Comment: To answer the question how a float can happen between two collapsed margins, that's because margins between two adjacent blocks still collapse if there's a floating element in between (that is, when technically they're not adjacent, but they still behave as if they are). [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/u3hdcy74/9/). Not sure about the "anonymous block parent taking part in the flow" though, so not posting an answer.

Comment: @MrLister an *anonymous block* is a kind of empty div with nothing. So we place that empty div and then the float will be placed considering that div. Basically like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kh93bxyt/